# Web Api con ASP.NET CORE como manejar las imagenes

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, webapi

Tengo una web api en asp.net core y utilizo JWT para validar las peticiones con la api, mi duda es cuando necesitamos subir imagenes, cual es la mejor formar de hacerlo, ya que actualmente guardo las imagenes en una carpeta de la api ya que si las subo en wwwroot quedarian disponibles para cualquier persona y la idea es que solo tengan acceso las personas que tenga el token, estube intentando traerme las imagenes desde un controlador es decir.

[image: Codigo para traer la imagen]

Pero el problema es que cuando trato de de mostrarlo en la vista no logro convertirlo en base64 ya que cuando hago el request si se muestra la imagen en herramientas de desarrollador en preview.

[image: Se muestra la imagen en el request]

Pero cuando trato de convertir la imagen en base64 no me funciona ya que me regresa en la data de la respuesta lo siguiente.

[image: Image Data]

Trate de utilizar la data de la siguiente manera pero no logre que funcionara.

[image: Codigo que estoy utilizando para mostrar la imagen pero no me funciona]

Esto es lo que se muestra en la data de la peticion de la imagen

[image: Esto es lo que se muestra en la data de la peticion]

el this.urlPhotoProfile lo utilizo para mostrar una imagen en VueJS es decir  pero no logro que funcione.

Hay una manera de resolver esto, o otra mejor solucion para el tratamiento de las imagenes.

Saludos...

Answer (score 1):

Ya logre resolverlo. Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema les anexo la solución

```
axios.get(`api/Image/${this.IdPaciente}/125x125/${nameImage}`,{ responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
    .then(response => {
         let imgBase64 = new Buffer(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64');
         let format = response.headers['content-type'];
         this.urlPhotoProfile = `data:${format};base64,${imgBase64}`;
     });
```